Unable to resolve task when pass artifact in loop argoworkflow
I got an error when I tried to pass an artifact between template in a loop argoworkflow. That's my error : Unable to resolve: "tasks.prv04-export-dataset-individu-to-csv-chunk.outputs.artifacts.output-dataset-individus-csv"
Actually the task in the loop is named "prv04-export-dataset-individu-to-csv-chunk(0:0)" since whe are in a boucle with list item 0 , 1 ,2 ...
Here is the main template :
templates:
    - name: prv04-parent-dataset-sbd-individu-wf
      dag:
        tasks:
        # calcul nombre de chunks du dataset pour export csv
        - name: prv04-calcul-nb-chunks-dataset-individu
          templateRef:
            name: prv04-export-encrypt-dataset-individu-wf-template
            template: prv04-calcul-nb-chunks-dataset-individu
        # process chunks
        # export csv
        - name: prv04-export-dataset-individu-to-csv-chunk
          dependencies: [prv04-calcul-nb-chunks-dataset-individu]
          templateRef:
            name: prv04-export-encrypt-dataset-individu-wf-template
            template: prv04-export-dataset-individu-to-csv-chunk
          withParam: "{{tasks.prv04-calcul-nb-chunks-dataset-individu.outputs.parameters.chunk-list}}"
          arguments:
            parameters:
            - name: numero-chunk
              value: "{{item}}"
        # encrypt data
        - name: prv04-encrypt-dataset-individu
          dependencies: [prv04-export-dataset-individu-to-csv-chunk]
          templateRef:
            name: prv04-export-encrypt-dataset-individu-wf-template
            template: prv04-encrypt-dataset-individu
          arguments:
              artifacts:
                - name: dataset-individus-csv
                  from: "{{tasks.prv04-export-dataset-individu-to-csv-chunk.outputs.artifacts.output-dataset-individus-csv}}"

Does anyone have an idea ?
pass artifact between template in a loop argo
